# Activerecord merge rows with same column value into one

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord

In my rails app, I am trying to combine data from multiple rows.

My Table looks like below.

```
Name    Office   Device
-----   ------   ------- 
USR-A    LA-HQ    MACBOOK
USR-B    LA-HQ    MACBOOK
USR-A    LA-HQ    IMAC
USR-B    NY-HQ    IMAC
USR-B    NY-HQ    IPHONE
```

I want the data to look like below

```
Name    Office   Device
-----   ------   ------- 
USR-A    LA-HQ    MACBOOK, IMAC
USR-B    LA-HQ    MACBOOK
USR-B    NY-HQ    IMAC, IPHONE
```

Comment: Your idea is to manipulate data after each fetch or need to rewrite data into the DB?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @muistooshort I am using postgres DB

Comment: @iGian No, I don't need to rewrite the data back to the db. I want the data minupulation on the db side for speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way with PostgreSQL would be to use [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

```
ms = Model.select('"Name", "Office", array_agg("Device") as "Devices"').group(:Name, :Office)
```

That will give you `Model`s in `ms` and each will have an extra `Devices` method that will give you the arrays of device strings.

Or you could use `string_agg`:

```
ms = Model.select('"Name", "Office", string_agg("Device", ',') as "Devices"').group(:Name, :Office)
```

and the `Devices` methods will give you strings instead of arrays.

Neither of those guarantee any particular order for the aggregation but you can [specify the order](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) if you want one:

```
array_agg("Device" order by "Device")
string_agg("Device", ',' order by "Device" desc)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to do with plain Ruby, which might be easier than trying to use SQL. Here's something to help you get started:

```
require 'ostruct'

rows = [
  OpenStruct.new(name: 'USR-A', office: 'LA-HQ', device: 'MACBOOK'),
  OpenStruct.new(name: 'USR-B', office: 'LA-HQ', device: 'MACBOOK'),
  OpenStruct.new(name: 'USR-A', office: 'LA-HQ', device: 'IMAC'),
  OpenStruct.new(name: 'USR-B', office: 'NY-HQ', device: 'IMAC'),
  OpenStruct.new(name: 'USR-B', office: 'NY-HQ', device: 'IPHONE'),
]

groups = rows.group_by { |i| "#{i.name}#{i.office}" }.values
groups = groups.map do |group|
  device = group.map(&:device).join(", ")
  OpenStruct.new(
    name: group.first.name,
    office: group.first.office,
    device: device
  )
end
p groups

=> [#<OpenStruct name="USR-A", office="LA-HQ", device="MACBOOK, IMAC">,
    #<OpenStruct name="USR-B", office="LA-HQ", device="MACBOOK">,
    #<OpenStruct name="USR-B", office="NY-HQ", device="IMAC, IPHONE">]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to do this on the database side for performance reason.